# Why does SQL query not use primary key for SELECT when it is most suitable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sqlperformance

**Scenario** (tried to come up with a 1-1 mapping to my production scenario): Fetch list of all people who flew with Virgin airlines or Emirates from New York.

**Table**: `tbl_Flyer` has a few columns containing all details about the people who flew at any point of time. The Primary key is `CountryId, CityId, AirlineId, PersonId`

Now, a simple SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT  flyer.PersonId
FROM    tbl_Flyer passenger
WHERE   passenger.CountryId = @countryId
        AND passenger.City= @cityId
        AND passenger.AirlineId IN (SELECT values FROM @allAirlineIds)
```

`@countryId` and `@cityId` and `@allAirlineIds` are properly sent to the SQL stored procedure. My assumption would be that this query would use the primary key as all the 4 columns being used in the query are present in PK, but for some reason it does not.
 It uses a non clustered index which was added to be able to query passengers on the basis of personal details like age, sex. (looks like (CountryId, CityId, Age, Sex))

I am adding a ForceSeek hint to the query but I want to understand if there is an anti-pattern that I might be using here? Any idea why SQL would defy logic and not use the PK for a seek?

Comment: You should avoid building such complicated primary key. Make a surrogate identity-column the primary key and append a unique constraint for any column combination you want. And I'd suggest to always use `exists` instead of `in (select...`.

Comment: the primary key helps to me to partition the data in the database, I don't have other straightforward options to partition data based on country.

Comment: Not sure if partitioning by country makes sens for flight data, but you probably have better understanding. Is this a real _partitioning_ or just a clustered index which "influences physical row order"? `Country` anyway has bad selectivity. There are not so many countries. Your index starts from country, on @allairlineids you have some estimation issues.

Comment: Just a guess but because it is partitioned it is not as efficient

Comment: Okay, lets just assume that the app does not let you enter the country/city data. It auto detects your location and enters these fields... Apologies that I have to play around with the country analogy here.

Comment: Some information missing here. What is the cardinality of the `@allAirlineIds` table? Also, did you try join with the `@allAirlineIds` table instead of using the `... IN (...)` way?

Comment: @divyanshm so real partitioning with partitioning function, files and so on or just a clustered index _not on id column_? And how many more columns are there in this table?

Comment: It would help a great deal if you could show the script of the table including all the indexes?

Answer (score 0):

The choice do by your Data Base Engine of using one index or another is automatically do based on automated heuristics... who are not always the most accurate. (99% of the times, they are, but sometimes, the human brain found a better way ).
This heuristics are calculated based on generalist rules, and sometime it don't match the reality of the content of your database.(string colonne with alway the same first letter, colonne with a lot of null, ...)

The "Select In" operation have to be done for each row of your table, and stocked  and is considered as extremly expensive by most of the data base engine, so your Data Base can prefere use another way.(non clustered index in your case)

Using Exist in is considered as far less expensive, by the way, and will make your Data base Engine more suspectible to choose the index.

use ForceSeek if it's not enought.

Also You can have the same issue if the type of CountryId, CityId, AirlineId, PersonId is not the same than @CountryId, @CityId, @AirlineId, @PersonId (the type conversion is expensive)